# Is there an algorithm (on the inernet) that converts points into possible functions for the points?

Tags: functions, algorithms, interpolation

Is there an algorithm where the input is a bunch of points and the output would be a possible function which includes these points? I've only found one website that gives you the correlating linear function for two points you have entered. This feature is quite limited because I have more than two points and the function shouldn't be a linear function.

In my problem, there are 5 known maxima that each have the same y value but a different x value. I know that there are infinite maxima. What I don't know is, if there are more maxima in between my known maxima or not. The x values of the points are all negative. The distances between the points shrink while you go towards positive $∞$. I didn't find any pattern (yet) regarding how they shrink. My best approach was something like

$$f(x)=a\sin \left(\frac{b}{x-c}\right)$$

but I didn't find any fitting parameters just by trial and error. That's why I asked if there is an algorithm for that.
The known maxima are:

$P_1\approx(-13 800 000 000;z)$

$P_2\approx(-4 280 000 000;z)$

$P_3\approx(-540 000 000;z)$

$P_4\approx(-2 000 000;z)$

$P_5\approx(-1 600;z)$

(These are just roundings because the numbers are very big and it doesn't matter that much/it doesn't have to be exact. It's irrelevant where the y values of the maxima are, so I'll just say the highest possible point is $z$.)

Comment: It would help to get a better description of the problem. It sounds like you're describing [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). If so there are multiple approaches depending on if you want to match the original data exactly or not.

Comment: @gt6989b Okay, so I have a bunch of Maxima and I want to get a function that isn't just a straight line/that isn't a constant. It should be something recurring or periodic that peaks at these points. It does not have to be exactly at these points but it shouldn't be too divergent.

Comment: If you have $n$ points which should be the maxima of your function, there should be $n-1$ relative minima between them, so you need to fit a polynomial of degree $2n$ to your points. You know the derivative has a linear factor for each of the maxima, which should make your life easier.

Comment: @gt6989b The problem is, that I don't know if I have all maxima. If I have all maxima the function can't be proportional because the distance between the neighbouring maxima isn't the same. Does your method still apply to this? And if I don't have all maxima I can't use your method because $n$ is unknown.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to account for your problem.

Comment: For any given number of points like you describe there are an infinite number of functions that have these as maxima. Interpolation algorithms might be able to give you one of those, but only based on specific classes of functions (polynomial, trigonometric) or restrictions (smoothness, degree). It seems like you a looking for quite a specific function. I would perhaps suggest expanding on where your data came from in the first place, in order that someone might help you come up with a suitable interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

To make my suggestion more real, suppose you want a function that will have relative maxima at $(-1,1)$ and $(1,2)$. As is clear, there should also be a relative minimum in the middle somewhere, let's pick it in the middle at $(a,b)$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, since we seem to be able to pick anything we like for the minima.

So we need a function with $3$ extrema, hence we will have a quartic polynomial $p(x)$. Its derivative is given by
$$
p'(x) = (x-1)(x-a)(x+1) = x^3-ax^2-x+a,
$$
since we know all the roots from the extrema. Now
$$
p(x) = x^4-\frac{ax^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}+ax+C
$$
and we have
$$
\begin{split}
1 &= p(-1) &= C - \frac{2a}{3} + \frac12 \\
b &= p(0)  &= C \\
2 &= p(1)  &= C + \frac{2a}{3} + \frac12 \\
\end{split}
$$
Which is a system of 3 linear equations in 3 unknowns, which you can solve and this will take care of finding $p$ exactly.

From the second equation you see $C = b$, and adding first and third together yields $3=2C+1 \iff C=1$, which implies $a=3/4$. So the result is
$$
p(x) = x^4-\frac{x^3}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3x}{4}+1
$$

Comment: I think this mathematics is just too advanced for me. I can neither follow nor understand it. But this method seems to work only if all maxima are known. In my problem, the number of maxima is infinte.

Comment: @Fritsch it would be nice to get an idea of a sample problem with the numbers -- infinite extrema can be constructed with trigonometric functions.

Comment: There are 5 known points that each have the same y value but a different x value. The x values of the points are all negative. The distances between the points shrink while you go towards positive ∞. I didn't find any pattern (yet) regarding how they shrink. My best approach was something like $f(x)=sin(a/(x-c))b$ but I didn't find any fitting parameters just by trial and error. That's why I asked here if there were any algorithms for that. Do you want the exact points?

Comment: @Fritsch yes, please. Update your question and post a comment here so I know to go look. Thanks

Comment: I updated the question and added the information I said in the comments earlier. I've never used LaTex and I'm not used to StackExchange so if there is anything wrong, please tell me.